# One of the styles doesn't work but the other do

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a web page to play a game. It uses two containers (inside a component). They show 2 images but by default they are empty. I apply one style to them: img-container which set the dimentions and color the background (it must be black), but the style doesn't work, although all other styles do.

Clarifications: At start, the div uses 2 classes (img-container and flex-child, which works fine). Also, I am working with Visual Studio Code.

I already try: change class name, reboot the host (closing VS Code an using 'npm start'), using another web browser (chrome and firefox) and change property values for bigger ones. This doesn't work but insert the properties in preexisting CSS classes and call they do.

Component code:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Class component
class PPT extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div id = "PPT">
            <h3 id="explanation">¿Cómo se juega? </h3>
            <div id="container" className="flex-parent">
                <div id="player_hand" className="flex-child">
                    <h2>Jugador</h2>
                    <div className="img-container"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="computer_hand" className="flex-child">
                    <h2>Computadora</h2>
                    <div className="img-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PPT;
```

CSS style:

```html
#PPT {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#img-container {
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 474px;
  height: 266px;
}
```

Comment: `#img-container` is an [**ID** selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors). It'll match an element with `id="img-container"`. But you have `<div className="img-container"></div>`, which sets a *class*, not an `id`. For that, the rule should use a [**class** selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#class-html), `.img-container`. See also MDN: [ID selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors),  [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `#img-container` while you must use `.img-container` because it's a class. I also suggest that you remove that `hyphen(-)` and use an `_` instead to maintain proper naming convention of classes in react and to also respect lint rule as your approach will show a warning in some editors. At the end your class name must look like `img_container` in jsx and like this `.img_conatiner` in css.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong part is this section in your JSX:

```
className="img-container"
```

since you are using className you have to provide a class in your related css file for it, like below:

```css
.img-container {
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 474px;
  height: 266px;
}
```

You are selecting your element in a wrong way!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, `#` is an ID selector, while `.` is a class selector. So, to target an element with class name `img-container`, you should use `.image-container`, and not `#img-container`.